# Refer To When Defining Plural Terms

Tags: verb-agreement, collective-nouns

I’m trying to figure out the reasoning for why “refers to” is always singular when using it to describe a term.

Is this not always the case? If not, please provide an example. If yes, is the word “the term” the implied subject?

For example:

Apex predators refers to several animals at the top of the food chain.

Is this correct or incorrect, and why? I know it’s poor style, but I want to find out if this is correct and why.

Comment: _Apex predators_ is a single term or expression, even though its meaning is plural.

Answer (score 2):

Because all "mentions" — that is, a word as a word itself — are singular nouns.

- That child **refers** to herself as *Tabitha*.
- *Child* here **refers** to the famous Julia Child.
- *Child* here **means** the famous Julia Child.
- Children **refer** to themselves as *kids*.
- *Children* **refers** to more than one child.
- *Children* **means** more than one child.
- Acts of God **are** never insured against.
- *Acts of God* **refers** to anything falling under force majeure exemptions.
- *Acts of God* **means** anything falling under force majeure exemptions.

Answer (score 0):

typically a stand-alone noun or phrase that must be defined will be "refers to."
But if you were to say, "'Man,' 'Human,' and 'Person' refer(s) to an individual of the species *Homo Sapiens*," the correct word would be "refer" because there are multiple items referring to a single meaning. You could also define different things in the same sentence, like:
"'Woman,' 'Man,' and 'Person' refer to human individuals of female, male, or unspecified gender, respectively."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).